# Форма не приходит на email(в спаме чисто)

Tags: php, backend, phpmailer

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];

$mail->isSMTP();

// $mail->Host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'berestovayamaria@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '';

$mail->addAddress('berestovayamaria@gmail.com');

$mail->Mailer = “smtp”;

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' оставил заявку, его телефон ' .$phone. '<br>Почта этого пользователя: ' .$email;
$mail->AltBody = '';

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

 $mail->setFrom('berestovayamaria@gmail.com', 'Сайт site.ru');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>

    <meta name="yandex-verification" content="11fe4c311d959174" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <title>Отправка формы на почту </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <style>
        form {
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <legend>Заголовок формы</legend>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите ваше имя</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Иван">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите номер телефона</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_phone" placeholder="+7 (999) 99 99 999">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Введите email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить форму</button>
            </form>
        </div><!-- .col-sm-4 -->
      </div> <!-- .row -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

После отправки формы файл php сообщает что сообщение успешно отправдено, но сообщение не приходит на email

Comment: или приходит в спам

Comment: `сообщение успешно отправдено, но сообщение приходит на email` так оно приходит, или всё-таки нет?

Comment: извиняюсь, исправила

Comment: Сервер какой используете? Локальный? Если локальный, то письма летят в спец папку, в зависимости что за сервер

Comment: open server использую